# SQL (Custom) Unique Constraint for a set of rows

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

How to create a ( may be custom) unique constraint for a particular no.of rows.

I have table data as below

[image]

I want my **itemFK** column to be Unique for same **productionsessionKey** value. i.e for all yellow (101) **itemFK** should be **Unique** and for all blue (102) **itemFK** should be **unique**. Else they can be duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [unique constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) on a tupple for those 2 columns

F.e.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Your_Table_ProdSession_Item UNIQUE (productionsessionKey, itemFK);
```

Comment: yes, it worked.

Comment: Oh good, I hoped you wouldn't request that it would only be for 2 specific id's. Cause that would be way harder, and weird.

Comment: Btw, for performance reasons you might have to decide if a constraint on `(productionsessionKey, itemFK)` or on `(itemFK, productionsessionKey)` is better. It depends on what other indexes exist, and what queries you run that could make use of the index.

Comment: i have other question posted just now, can you check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70723861/sql-unique-and-foreign-key-of-a-column-from-other-tables-column-which-itself-i